# bash not automatically launched with sudo

Tags: bash, debian, sudo

I have debian.
When my user tries to change to root via sudo, bash does not automatically launched(((

```
blog@debian:/var/web/Blog$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for blog: 
#
```

What should I do? I can not use tab to complete commands automatically or use up button to view history.

Comment: How do you know bash is not started? I see a prompt `#` there and I assume that's printed by some shell. How do you know it's not bash? What happens when you `echo $SHELL` and `echo $0`?

Comment: # echo $SHELL
/bin/sh But I want bash.

Comment: Okay, so what's the output of  `echo $SHELL` BEFORE you `sudo -s`?

Comment: blog@debian:/var/web/Blog$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page of `sudo(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> `-s [command]`
>
> The `-s` (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in the password database. If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's `-c` option. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

Therefore, if you want to start in bash, you have to

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

in your shell before you do `sudo -s`.

Comment: How to do it automatically? So I dont do it each time?

Comment: @ovod You have to do it in each shell once. You can add that to your rc. But I have a question here: what's your user's default shell? `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`? I'm surprised by your `$SHELL` in the first place.

Comment: In my .profile exec /bin/bash but echo $SHELL gives /bin/sh(((

Comment: @ovod That's the correct behavior. You shouldn't do `exec /bin/bash` in `sh` to get a bash shell. What you should do instead is change your login shell: run `chsh -s /bin/bash`. Alternatively, you can add `export SHELL=/bin/bash` to your `.bashrc`, but that's really not recommended, as `chsh` is *the* right solution.